# ffmpeg audio and video sync error

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, pandaboard

```
./ffmpeg \
-f alsa -async 1 -ac 2 -i hw:2,0 \
-f video4linux2 -vsync 1 -s:v vga -i /dev/video0 \
-acodec aac -b:a 40k \
-r 25 -s:v vga -vcodec libx264 -strict -2 -crf 25 -preset fast -b:v 320K -pass 1 \
-f flv rtmp://192.168.2.105/live/testing
```

with the above command i able to stream with fps of 25 but their is no audio and video synchronization i.e., audio is faster than video,i am using ffmpeg 0.11.1 version on the pandaboard for an rtmp streaming ,help me out to solve this problem.

Thanks

Ameeth

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `-pass 1` if you're not actually doing two-pass encoding.

From the docs (emphasis added):

> **`‘-pass[:stream_specifier] n (output,per-stream)’`**
>   Select the pass number (1 or 2). It is used to do two-pass video encoding. The statistics of the video are recorded in the first pass into a log file (see also the option -passlogfile), and in the second pass that log file is used to generate the video at the exact requested bitrate. **On pass 1, you may just deactivate audio and set output to null**, examples for Windows and Unix:
>
> ```
> ffmpeg -i foo.mov -c:v libxvid -pass 1 -an -f rawvideo -y NUL
> ffmpeg -i foo.mov -c:v libxvid -pass 1 -an -f rawvideo -y /dev/null
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I was streaming to Twitch, and, funnily enough, removing the `-r` option made video sync with the audio. Now, you might want to have the framerate limited in some way; unfortunately, I have no solution for that, but it does allow to sync the video with the audio very well.